# Why is Rust's .expect() called expect?

Tags: rust

Rust's `.expect()` is one of the most surprising names in the Result/Option space. While `unwrap` makes sense -- get a value from a `Result` by "unwrapping" it -- `expect` is surprisingly counterintuitive (to me).

Since so much of Rust is inspired by conventions from functional programming languages, I have been assuming that this is another example of "strange homage to obscurity," but when I asked the Duck it couldn't find an answer for me.

So, I give up. Why is `.expect()` the name for Rust's `.unwrap_or_panic_with_this_message()` function? Is this a reference to a feature in yet another functional language? Is it back-handed shade (or a complement) to Tcl? The result of too many late nights and too much Espresso at Mozilla?

What is the etymology of this plucky (but fierce!) little member of the standard library?

**Edit:**

Great news, everyone! After more than a year, we now have both an "explanation" in @GManNickG's tremendously well-researched and documented answer, below, and a "mental model" provided by @Peng's comment and link:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/index.html#common-message-styles

In short, it is now recommended that diagnostics for `expect()` should be written as "expect...should" or maybe "expect...should have". This makes more sense in the diagnostic output (see the link for examples) but also makes the source code scan better:

```
foo.expect("something bad happened")    // NO!

foo.expect("gollywumpus should be current") // YES!
```

Comment: I can "expect" a result to be `Ok`, I can "expect" an Optional value to be `Some`. I can also write in test, where I "expect" a web request to be successful. I would write `do_request().expect("Expected request to be successful")`. This gives me a clear and concise message of what went wrong instead of having to go through the stacktrace when using `unwrap`.

Comment: I'm torn. On the (-1) hand, this question triggers my "superfluous historical question inviting speculation with no pragmatic value" reflex, but on the (+1) hand, Nick's answer is really good and shows that it is sometimes possible for speculation to also be a good answer. I still don't think that SO is the right place to ask these kinds of questions, though, so I'm compelled to agree with the close vote.

Comment: I'm surprised at the closure of this question. I wasn't inviting speculation or opinion, I was *expecting* (ahem!) something like, "It was copied from *language-X* along with all these other things".

Comment: I agree with @aghast as a noob to Rust this name seems counterintuitive. I "expect" the method to work... but if "error" or "onError" on "unexpected" or "exception" occurs then show a message.  So it may be "quite natural" to some but sure isn't to me.  Seems to be the exact opposite name I would have given it.

Comment: Late to the question, but as this is a common confusion/annoyance for beginners of Rust: this has been explained very thoroughly in the Rust styling guide now at [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/index.html#common-message-styles). In a summary: Rust recommends `expect as precondition` for better code readability, therefore you are recommended to put `expect("Something should have happened")` instead of `expect("Something went wrong")`.

Comment: @Peng, thanks for the update and the link! I like this model, and I think if I had seen that explanation I would not have been so confused originally. (The fact that this "closed" question continues to increase in score is a source of warm schadenfreude -- others are suffering, but also curious!) I think the docs might benefit from pointing out that "should" and "expect" are complementary in English. Writing `expect("something bad happened")` really is the root of the problem. Either `expect("something should happen")` or `oh_noes("something bad happened")` would be an improvement. :-)

Comment: @Peng In fact, I think the Murphy (everything-that-can-go-wrong-go-wrong-Murphy) interpretability of `expect` is not unintentional.

Comment: But the official documentation introduces `expect` like this: `expect("Failed to read line")`. That violates the `expect("something should happen")` convention. People (who still read docs) will run into this very early, and it doesn't make a good impression.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Summary:**

No explicit reason for the name is given. However, it is incredibly likely the name comes from the world of *parsers*, where one "expects" to see a particular token (else the compilation fails).

Within rustc, the use of `expect`-like functions long predate use within `Option`. These are functions like `expect(p, token::SEMI)` to expect to parse a semicolon and `expect_word(p, "let")` to expect to parse the `let` keyword. If the expectation isn't met, compilation fails with an error message.

Eventually a utility function was added within the compiler that would expect not a specific token or string, but that a given `Option` contained a value (else, fail compilation with the given error message). Over time this was moved to the `Option` struct itself, where it remains today.

Personally, I don't find it unusual at all. It's just another verb you can *do* to the object, like unwrapping or taking or mapping its value. Expecting a value (else, fail) from your `Option` seems quite natural.

---

**History:**

The oldest commit of note is the following:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/b06dc884e57644a0c7e9c5391af9e0392e5f49ac

Which adds this function within the compiler:

```rust
fn expect<T: copy>(sess: session, opt: option<T>, msg: fn() -> str) -> T {
    alt opt {
       some(t) { t }
       none { sess.bug(msg()); }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the first function named "expect" that deals with inspecting an `Option`. Observe in particular this example use-case within the commit (which was implementing support for class methods!):

```rust
#debug("looking up %? : %?", def, class_doc);
let the_field = expect(tcx.sess,
    decoder::maybe_find_item(def.node, class_doc),
    {|| #fmt("get_field_type: in class %?, field ID %? not found",
             class_id, def)});
```

If the result of `decoder::maybe_find_item` is `None`, compilation will fail with the given error.

I encourage you to look at the parser code in this commit - there is extensive use of other `expect`-esque functions: e.g., `expect(p, token::RPAREN)` and `expect_word(p, "let")`. The name of this new function is almost obvious in this environment.

Eventually, the utility of this function was extracted and placed within `Option` itself:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/e000d1db0ab047b8d2949de4ab221718905ce3b1

Which looked like:

```rust
pure fn expect<T: copy>(opt: option<T>, reason: str) -> T {
    #[doc = "
    Gets the value out of an option, printing a specified message on failure
    # Failure
    Fails if the value equals `none`
    "];
    alt opt { some(x) { x } none { fail reason; } }
}
```

It's worth noting that sometime later, there was eventually an (additional) function named `unwrap_expect` added in:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/be3a71a1aa36173ce2cd521f811d8010029aa46f

```rust
pure fn unwrap_expect<T>(-opt: option<T>, reason: ~str) -> T {
    //! As unwrap, but with a specified failure message.
    if opt.is_none() { fail reason; }
    unwrap(opt)
}
```

Over time these were both subsumed by an `Expect` *trait*, which `Option` implemented:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/0d8f5fa618da00653897be2050980c800389be82

```rust
/// Extension trait for the `Option` type to add an `expect` method

// FIXME(#14008) should this trait even exist?
pub trait Expect<T> {
    /// Unwraps an option, yielding the content of a `Some`
    ///
    /// # Failure
    ///
    /// Fails if the value is a `None` with a custom failure message provided by
    /// `msg`.
    fn expect<M: Any + Send>(self, m: M) -> T;
}
```

Spoiler for that TODO: that trait no longer exists. It was removed shortly after per:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14008.

More or less this is where we are at today.

I think the most likely conclusion is that the use of `expect` as a meaningful function name long predates its use in `Option`. Given it says what it does (expect a value or fail) there is little reason to break the pattern.

Comment: The oldest commit with `expect()` seems to be https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/0937c10f3ca21585f0cb00c1a112e4ff4a742456 and it implements https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1119-result-expect.html

Comment: I think the `Option::expect()` was first added in https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust/commit/e000d1db0ab047b8d2949de4ab221718905ce3b1 and fixed in https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust/commit/aa909dc60a172a6dd1b3788818364c0768b1ea84 – unfortunately, no rationale was given in the commit message nor comments why this wasn't called `unwrap_or_panic()` instead.